# F# Group or aggregate a record sequence/collection by a given criteria

Tags: f#, functional-programming, grouping, aggregate

I am pretty new to functional programming and therefore F# and I have serious trouble to come up with the right solution for this problem.

I have got a sequence of record types, say like:

```
type Invoice = {
    GrpText : string
    GrpRef : int
    Article : int
    Wkz : int
    Text : string
    Price : decimal
    InvoiceRef : int
}
```

Now I want to group or aggregate the sequence of `Invoices` by a given criteria and i.e. sum their prices. `Invoices` that does not match the criteria should not be grouped and just returned as they are.

A criteria function might look like this:

```
/// determines whether to group the two given Invoice items or not
let criteria item toCompareWith =
    (item.GrpRef > 0 && item.Article = toCompareWith.Article
        && item.InvoiceRef = toCompareWith.InvoiceRef) ||
    (item.Wkz <> 0 && item.Text = toCompareWith.Text)
```

The aggregation or grouping could look like this:

```
/// aggregate the given Invoice items
let combineInvoices item1 item2 =
    {item1 with Price = item1.Price + item2.Price; Wkz = 0}
```

The problem looks kind of simple but I am currently not experienced enough in functional programming to connect the dots.

**Edit:**

I just modified the `criteria` function in order to better show that it might be a bit more complex than grouping by one or multiple fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, there are two steps involved: group and reduce. The easiest way to group is `Seq.groupBy`. Since you want to use custom equality you need to either apply the `[<CustomEquality>]` attribute to your type and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, or roll your own key generating function that uses your concept of equality. Here's an example of the latter.

```
//custom key generator
let genKeyWith compare =
  let lookup = ResizeArray()
  fun item ->
    match Seq.tryFindIndex (compare item) lookup with
    | Some idx -> idx
    | None ->
      lookup.Add(item)
      lookup.Count - 1
```

#### Usage

```
let getKey = genKeyWith criteria

let invoices = Seq.init 10 (fun _ -> Unchecked.defaultof<Invoice>)

invoices 
|> Seq.groupBy getKey
|> Seq.map (fun (_, items) -> Seq.reduce combineInvoices items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this where Defaultinvoice is some sort of '0' invoice

```
input 
|> Seq.groupBy (fun t -> t.Article) 
|> Seq.map (fun (a,b) -> a, (b |> List.fold (fun (c,d) -> combineInvoices c d) Defaultinvoice)
```

EDIT - For more complicated combine function.

So if your combine function is more complicated, the best approach is probably to use recursion and I think it is going to be hard to avoid a O(n^2) solution.  I would go with something like

```
let rec overallfunc input =
    let rec func input (valid:ResizeArray<_>) =
        match input with
        |[] -> valid //return list
        |h::t -> 
            match valid.tryfindIndex (fun elem -> criteria h elem) with //see if we can combine with something
            |Some(index) -> valid.[index] <- combineInvoices (valid.[index]) h //very non-functional here
            |None -> valid.Add(h)
            func t valid //recurse here
    func input (ResizeArray<_>())
```

This solution is both highly non-functional and probably very slow, but it should work for arbitrarily complicated combination functions

Comment: I think this one goes into the right direction but I there is one problem left I think. You are just grouping by the `Article` and I am not quite sure where or how I can integrate the `criteria` function or an even more complex one there.

Comment: @kongo2002 what if you do this `type comparison = {InvoiceRef:int;Article:int}` and then add `member x.Comp() = {InvoiceRef=x.InvoceRef;Article=x.Article` to your Invoice Item - then you can do `groupBy (fun t -> t.Comp())` - although you can't get the groupref comparison - perhaps use a Filter for that?

Comment: Alright then it would be the core of the question how to apply a filter to your described construct? :-) Btw, I just edited my initial post to better show the possible character/complexity of the `criteria` function.